# Crear un trigger que almacene en una tabla de auditoría el registro de todos los cambios que se hagan sobre la tabla order details

Tags: sql-server, trigger, mssql, microsoft

La estructura de la tabla de auditoría sería la misma de la tabla order details más los campos consecutivo (será la clave primaria) y el tipo de transacción (inserción o borrado).

Este es el script para crear la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails_Audit(
    Consecutivo INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, -- El valor de la 
    columna se incrementa automáticamente
[OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Discount] [real] NOT NULL,
Tipo_Trans varchar(15) -- Tipo transacción (inserción o borrado))
```

--trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_Auditoria 
ON OrderDetails
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO OrderDetails_Audit
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Delete'
                FROM deleted;
     END

     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO OrderDetails_Audit
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Insert'
                FROM inserted;
     END
```

He intentado con esto pero no me funciona y quiero que quede todo en un mismo trigger.

El error que me sale:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tg_Auditoria, Line 7 [Batch
> Start Line 0] An explicit value for the identity column in table
> 'OrderDetails_Audit' can only be specified when a column list is used
> and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: el error que me sale:

**Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tg_Auditoria, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'OrderDetails_Audit' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.**

Answer (score 0):

> An explicit value for the identity column in table
> 'OrderDetails_Audit' can only be specified when a column list is used
> and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

El error es bastante claro, estas intentando actualizar explicitamente la columna `Consecutivo` que es `INDENTITY`, esto el motor no lo permite a menos que uses un `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, pero no es tu caso, por que el valor de la columna debe ser efectivamente automático. Ocurre que estás haciendo una inserción sin especificar las columnas a actualizar, por lo que el motor induce que quieres actualizar `Consecutivo`, además haces un `select *` lo cual en una inserción es una mala práctica, cuando agregues o quites una columna a la tabla tu consulta se "romperá".

La solución es una inserción explicita:

```
INSERT INTO OrderDetails_Audit (OrderID, ProductID, 
                                UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount, Tipo_Trans)
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount, Tipo_Trans
       FROM deleted;
```

Comentarios:

- Este sería el modelo de inserción, replicalo en las dos inserciones que haces
- Hay columnas que no estaban definidas en la tabla, por eso no las puse en el ejemplo, hablo de la fecha del cambio `GETDATE()` y del tipo de operación `Delete/Insert`, agregalas el las columnas a insertar
- Estoy asumiendo que los nombres de columnas de `OrderDetails` son los mismos que definiste en `OrderDetails_Audit`, si no es asi, simplemente modifica el `SELECT`
- Por cierto, no necesitas registrar el `delete` y el `insert`, solo el primero es necesario. El evento de `insert` corresponde siempre al próximo `delete